# Is it possible to have a ampersand/& in a Column alias name short of using "Define Off" or "Set Escape" in Oracle Sql?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, alias, ampersand

first time poster.  I am using Oracle Sql Developer as my platform.

Here is a sample script of what I would like to do:

```
Select
  store AS "B & G"

From
  saleslocations
```

Result(preferred) would be a column header labeled "B & G".

If I leave it as is, I get a pop up asking for a variable, which is not what I need, as I want to keep the literal.

I have tried these two options:

1)Set Escape ; it works, but kind of runs funky in Oracle Sql Developer.

2)Define Off;  it works as well, but kind of runs funky in Oracle Sql Developer.

Other than these two options, is there any other thoughts, ideas, or functions worth trying?

I can of course do the usual suspects:  B&G, B and G, B&&G, etc., but I was just wondering if it is possible to keep it as "B & G"?

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

If I only knew what "funky" means. Because, I don't see anything like that in my SQL Developer 21.2. `set define off` works just fine.

[image]

Comment: LOL, fair enough.  Funky would, in this instance, be defined as I have a whole bunch of OLAP statements, and sometimes, even though "set define off", it will try to say that it needs a variable, intermittently.  Is this just the nature of the beast?